# Refreshing data in ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

In my screen I have a ui-grid that need be load when the user click in button "search".

I'm making this:

```js
// Ajax call

$("#btn-Pesquisar").click(function () {
  var form = $('#frm-Pesquisar-Acos-Internos');
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr('action'),
    dataType: "json",
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
      angular.element(document.getElementById('grd-Resultado')).scope().atualizarRegistros(JSON.parse(result));
      $('#divResultadoPesquisa').show();
    }
  });
});
```

When the call ocurred with success, I call a function called "atualizarRegistros"

```js
$scope.atualizarRegistros = function (result) {
  $scope.grdResultado.data = result;
}
```

This is a definition from my grid:

```js
$scope.grdResultado = {
  showGridFooter: true,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableColumnResizing: true,
  enableGridMenu: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { name: 'Código', field: 'COD_GRUPO_ACO', minWidth: 48 },
    { name: 'Norma', field: 'COD_IDENT_NORMA', minWidth: 60 }
  ]
};
```

the result is:

> [{"COD_IDENT_ACO":"C0981","COD_GRUPO_ACO":"C","COD_SUBGR_ACO":"0","COD_GRUPO_SUCAT":"04","COD_GRUPO_CUSTO":"36","COD_IDENT_FMACO":"5XX","NOM_IDENT_ACO":"P595R","COD_SITUA_ACO":"A","IDC_ACO_TRANS":"N","DTH_INCLU_REG":"2005-11-23T12:13:36","COD_IDENT_USUAR":"AC42911","COD_UNMED_PESES":"G/CM3","COD_GRUPO_ENCHA":null,"COD_ACO_MATPR":null,"COD_SERIE_ACO":null,"COD_IDENT_NORMA":"ACE","COD_TIPO_ACO":"P595R","NOM_ABREV_ACO":"595R","VLR_DIAME_IDEAL":null,"VLR_PESO_ESPEC":7.850,"VLR_TEMT1_LINGO":null,"VLR_TEMT2_LINGO":null,"TEX_OBSER_ACO":"Adição
>   de Ca-Si para globulizar inclusões, processo de desgazeificação no
>   VOD, projeto Flapper Valve.","VLR_TEMTP_LINGO":null,"DESC_ACO":"P595R
>   - ACE"}]

But when the method is executed, I get this error:
**newRawData.forEach is not a function at Grid.modifyRows**

I don't know what i can do now.

Help-me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you check,  if the data gets an array.

Greets Christian